# Could you please suggest a very dense book?

Tags: book-rec

I'm getting ready for the GRE and am looking for some highly challenging books. Any new bombastic dense context with long weird complex sentences would work for me. I would like to see who dense a context can be, and again, I'm not looking for something overly archaic that only a neanderthal could fully understand!

Comment: Hi Nate, welcome to Writers SE. This is not on-topic for us, as it's not about writing or editing. (That said, Gabriel Garcia-Marquez's *Autumn of the Patriarch* ought to do you nicely. I counted six sentences stretched over 40 pages before I threw it across the room.)

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Thank you for your response. I'll soon get the translated version of that book. Where do you suggest I should post this question to get more answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Doctor Faustus* by Thomas Mann. I found it extraordinarily challenging, and worth it. Twice.

Comment: Thank you. I found more that one book titled Doctor Faustus. Before I purchase, would you please check if this is the one you suggested?
http://tinyurl.com/n2tu4hv
Translated from German by John E. Woods.

Comment: Of the two that I read, the John E. Woods translation is by far my favorite. I forget who translated the other one I read.